# How to continually add data to a label until I press a specific button in Visual C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I made a simple calculator and it works perfectly. I've added a textbox and a label. textbox shows the result while the label shows the current operation. I want to keep showing values that I type in the label until i press the equal button to get the answer. for example I add 1 + 2 + 3

the label should show --> 1 + 2 +3 
the textbox should show --> 6 as the final answer.

Here is my code.

```
namespace My_First_Calculator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Double resultVal = 0;
        String operationPerformed = "";
        bool isOperationPerformed = false;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //common method to other number buttons
        {
            if (textBox_Result.Text == "0" || isOperationPerformed)
                textBox_Result.Clear();

            isOperationPerformed = false;
            Button button = (Button)sender;

            if(button.Text == ".")
            {
                if(!textBox_Result.Text.Contains("."))
                    textBox_Result.Text = textBox_Result.Text + button.Text;
            }
            else
            textBox_Result.Text = textBox_Result.Text + button.Text;
        }

        private void operator_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;
            if (resultVal != 0)
            {
                buttonEqual.PerformClick();
                operationPerformed = button.Text;
                labelCurrentOpration.Text = labelCurrentOpration.Text + resultVal + " " + operationPerformed;
                isOperationPerformed = true;
            }
            else
            {
                operationPerformed = button.Text;
                resultVal = Double.Parse(textBox_Result.Text);
                labelCurrentOpration.Text = labelCurrentOpration.Text + resultVal + " " + operationPerformed;
                isOperationPerformed = true;
            }
        }

        private void button18_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //buttonClaerAll
        {
            textBox_Result.Text = "0";
            resultVal = 0;
            labelCurrentOpration.Text = "";
        }

        private void button17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //buttonClear
        {
            textBox_Result.Text = "0";
            //resultVal = 0;
        }

        private void button16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //buttonEqual
        {
            switch(operationPerformed)
            {
                case "+": 
                    textBox_Result.Text = (resultVal + Double.Parse(textBox_Result.Text)).ToString();
                    break;
                case "-":
                    textBox_Result.Text = (resultVal - Double.Parse(textBox_Result.Text)).ToString();
                    break;
                case "*":
                    textBox_Result.Text = (resultVal * Double.Parse(textBox_Result.Text)).ToString();
                    break;
                case "/":
                    textBox_Result.Text = (resultVal / Double.Parse(textBox_Result.Text)).ToString();
                    break;
                default: break;
            }

            resultVal = Double.Parse(textBox_Result.Text);
            labelCurrentOpration.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

[image: My Calculator]

Comment: Always name your controls something meaningful! It'll save you -- and anyone else who maintains your code -- headache later when you see `clearButton` instead of `button18`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append the new string to the existing text in the label.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox_Result.Text == "0" || isOperationPerformed)
        textBox_Result.Clear();

    isOperationPerformed = false;
    Button button = (Button)sender;

    if(button.Text == ".")
    {
        if(!textBox_Result.Text.Contains("."))
            textBox_Result.Text = textBox_Result.Text + button.Text;
    }
    else
        textBox_Result.Text = textBox_Result.Text + button.Text;

    labelCurrentOperation.Text = labelCurrentOperation.Text + " " + button.Text;
}


private void operator_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    if (resultVal != 0)
    {
        button16.PerformClick();
        operationPerformed = button.Text;
        labelCurrentOpration.Text = labelCurrentOpration.Text + " " + resultVal + " " + operationPerformed;
        isOperationPerformed = true;
    }
    else
    {
        operationPerformed = button.Text;
        resultVal = Double.Parse(textBox_Result.Text);
        labelCurrentOpration.Text = labelCurrentOpration.Text + " " + resultVal  + " " + operationPerformed;
            isOperationPerformed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok it partially works but i want the label to show everything i input such as 1+ 2 + 3 + 10 - 6 <--- this should display in the label while the textbox displaying the result. it could be in a loop i think but not sure how to code it. Please help.

Comment: @AshaneAlvis See my edit. I'm guessing a bit as your method names aren't clear. The point is that you just need to append the new string to the existing text.

Comment: No it the above answer didn't work at all. It just duplicate s the numbers like if i press 3 and click the add or subtract button it just duplicates as 33.

Comment: Just look at the Microsoft default calculator in windows 8.1 it shows on top right corner what are the operations done so far (until I press CE button which clears all the fields). I just need to implement that. Can you help me out?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I need some help. Can you see to this?